# how to extract ip address from QueueDiscItem in ns3?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ns-3

I'm new to NS3 and i was trying to extract ip address of a packet from QueueDiscItem,

when i have:
Ptr< QueueDiscItem > item initiated and call:

```
item->Print(std::cout);
```

the output i get is
"tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 63 id 265 protocol 6 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 76 10.1.4.2 > 10.1.2.1 0x7fffc67ec880 Dst addr 02-06-ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff proto 2048 txq"

but when i call:

```
Ipv4Header header;
item->GetPacket()->PeekHeader(header);
header.Print(std::cout);
```

the output i get is
"tos 0x0 DSCP Default ECN Not-ECT ttl 0 id 0 protocol 0 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 20 102.102.102.102 > 102.102.102.102"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to get the `Header` data

According to the [list of TraceSources](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/_trace_source_list.html), the TraceSources associated with QueueDiscItems are for Queues. I'm guessing you were trying to attach to one of those TraceSources.

A [`QueueDiscItem`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_queue_disc_item.html) encapsulates several things: a `Ptr<Packet>`, a MAC address, and several more things. Since you are using IPv4, the `QueueDiscItem` is actually an [`Ipv4QueueDiscItem`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_ipv4_queue_disc_item.html) (the latter is a subclass of the former). So, let's start by casting the `QueueDiscItem` to an `Ipv4QueueDiscItem` by

```cpp
Ptr<const Ipv4QueueDiscItem> ipItem = DynamicCast<const Ipv4QueueDiscItem>(item);
```

Next, you need to know that at this point in the simulation, the `Ipv4Header` **has not** been added to the `Ptr<Packet>` yet. This is probably a design choice (that I don't understand). So, how can we get this information? Well, the `Ipv4QueueDiscItem` encapsulates the `Ipv4Header`, and at some point before passing the `Ptr<Packet>` to L2, the header is added to the packet. This `Header` can be retrieved by

```cpp
const Ipv4Header ipHeader = ipItem->GetHeader();
```

So, now we have the [`Ipv4Header`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_ipv4_header.html) of the packet you're interested in. Now, we can safely get the address from the `Ipv4QueueDiscItem` by

```cpp
ipHeader.GetSource();
ipHeader.GetDestination();
```

In summary, your TraceSource function should look something like this:

```cpp
void
EnqueueTrace (Ptr<const QueueDiscItem> item) {
    Ptr<const Ipv4QueueDiscItem> ipItem = DynamicCast<const Ipv4QueueDiscItem>(item);
    const Ipv4Header ipHeader = ipItem->GetHeader();
    NS_LOG_UNCOND("Packet received at " << Simulator::Now() << " going from " << ipHeader.GetSource() << " to " << ipHeader.GetDestination());
}
```

---

### Why does `item->Print(std::cout);` work?

All of the above makes sense, but why does

```cpp
item->Print(std::cout);
```

print the correct addresses? First, it is important to realize that here `Print()` is a function of the `QueueDiscItem`, not the `Packet`. If we go to [the source](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/ipv4-queue-disc-item_8cc_source.html#l00072) of this function, we find that `Print()` just prints the `Header` if it has already been added.